# In Rails How to display errors in my comment form after I submit it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a very straight-forward task to fulfil --- just to be able to write comments under posts and if the comments fail validation display error messages on the page.

My comment model uses a gem called Acts_as_commentable_with_threading, which creates a comment model after I installed.

On my post page, the logic goes like this:

Posts#show => display post and a form to enter comments => after the comment is entered, redisplay the Post#show page which has the new comment if it passes validation, otherwise display the error messages above the form.

However with my current code I can't display error messages if the comment validation fails. I think it is because when I redisplay the page it builds a new comment so the old one was erased. But I don't know how to make it work.

My codes are like this:

Comment.rb:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Humanizer
  require_human_on :create

  acts_as_nested_set :scope => [:commentable_id, :commentable_type]

  validates :body, :presence => true
  validates :first_name, :presence => true
  validates :last_name, :presence => true

  # NOTE: install the acts_as_votable plugin if you
  # want user to vote on the quality of comments.
  #acts_as_votable

  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true

  # NOTE: Comments belong to a user
  belongs_to :user

  # Helper class method that allows you to build a comment
  # by passing a commentable object, a user (could be nil), and comment text
  # example in readme
  def self.build_from(obj, user_id, comment, first_name, last_name)
     new \
        :commentable => obj,
        :body        => comment,
        :user_id     => user_id,
        :first_name  => first_name,
        :last_name   => last_name
  end
end
```

PostController.rb:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def show
      @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
      @new_comment = Comment.build_from(@post, nil, "", "", "")
  end
end
```

CommentsController:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

def create
    @comment = build_comment(comment_params)
    respond_to do |format|
        if @comment.save
            make_child_comment
            format.html
            format.json { redirect_to(:back, :notice => 'Comment was successfully added.')}
        else
            format.html
            format.json { redirect_to(:back, :flash => {:error => @comment.errors}) }
        end
    end
end

private
    def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:user, :first_name, :last_name, :body, :commentable_id, :commentable_type, :comment_id,
            :humanizer_answer, :humanizer_question_id)
    end

    def commentable_type
        comment_params[:commentable_type]
    end

    def commentable_id
        comment_params[:commentable_id]
    end

    def comment_id
        comment_params[:comment_id]
    end

    def body
        comment_params[:body]
    end

    def make_child_comment
        return "" if comment_id.blank?

        parent_comment = Comment.find comment_id
        @comment.move_to_child_of(parent_comment)
    end

    def build_comment(comment_params)
        if current_user.nil?
            user_id = nil 
            first_name =  comment_params[:first_name]
            last_name = comment_params[:last_name]
        else
            user_id = current_user.id
            first_name = current_user.first_name
            last_name = current_user.last_name
        end
        commentable = commentable_type.constantize.find(commentable_id)
        Comment.build_from(commentable, user_id, comment_params[:body],
                    first_name, last_name)
    end
end
```

comments/form: (this is on the Posts#show page)

```
<%= form_for @new_comment do |f| %>  
  <% if @new_comment.errors.any? %>
    <div id="errors">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@new_comment.errors.count, "error") %> encountered, please check your input.</h2>

        <ul>
            <% @new_comment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The normal convention for multi-line initialization is to do `new(` and then the contents on the next line. The backslash you're using there is really unusual.

Comment: @tadman this file was auto-created by the gem. I just changed its arguments.

Comment: That's even stranger then.

Answer (score 1):

I would instead use nested routes to create a more restful and less tangled setup:

```
concerns :commentable do
  resources :comments, only: [:create]
end

resources :posts, concerns: :commentable
```

This will give you a route `POST /posts/1/comments` to create a comment.

In your controller the first thing you want to do is figure out what the parent of the comment is:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_commentable

  private
    def set_commentable
      if params[:post_id]
        @commentable = Post.find(params[:post_id])
      end
    end
end
```

This means that we no longer need to pass the `commentable` as form parameters. Its also eliminates this unsafe construct:

```
commentable = commentable_type.constantize.find(commentable_id)
```

Where a malicous user could potentially pass any class name as `commentable_type` and you would let them find it in the DB... Never trust user input to the point where you use it to execute any kind of code!

With that we can start building our create action:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_commentable

  def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params) do |comment|
      if current_user
       comment.user = current_user
       comment.first_name =  current_user.first_name
       comment.last_name = current_user.last_name
      end
    end

    if @comment.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { head :created, location: @comment }
        format.html { redirect_to @commentable, success: 'Comment created' }
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: 422 }
      end
    end
  end


  private
  # ...

    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :body, :humanizer_answer, :humanizer_question_id)
    end
end
```

In Rails when the user submits a form you do not redirect the user back to the form - instead you re-render the form and send it as a response.

While you could have your CommentsController render the show view of whatever the commentable is it will be quite brittle and may not even provide a good user experience since the user will see the top of the post they where commenting. Instead we would render `app/views/comments/new.html.erb` which should just contain the form.

Also pay attention to how we are responding. You should generally avoid using `redirect_to :back` since it relies on the client sending the `HTTP_REFERRER` header with the request. Many clients do not send this!

Instead use `redirect_to @commentable` or whatever resource you are creating.

In your original code you have totally mixed up JSON and HTML responses. 
When responding with JSON you do not redirect or send flash messages.

If a JSON POST request is successful you would either:

- Respond with [`HTTP 201 - CREATED`](https://httpstatuses.com/201) and a location header which contains the url to the newly created resource. This is preferred when using SPA's like Ember or Angular.
- Respond with `HTTP 200 - OK` and the resource as JSON in the response body. This is often done in legacy API's.

If it fails do to validations you should respond with `422 - Unprocessable Entity` - usually the errors are rendered as JSON in the response body as well.

### Added.

You can scrap your `Comment.build_from` method as well which does you no good at all and is very idiosyncratic Ruby.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def show
      @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
      @new_comment = @post.comments.new
  end
end
```

Don't use line contiuation (`\`) syntax like that - use parens.

**Don't:**

```
new \
        :commentable => obj,
        :body        => comment,
        :user_id     => user_id,
        :first_name  => first_name,
        :last_name   => last_name
```

**Do:**

```
new(
 foo: a,
 bar: b
)
```

### Added 2

When using `form_for` with nested resources you pass it like this:

```
<%= form_for([commentable, comment]) do |f| %>

<% end %>
```

This will create the correct url for the `action` attribute and bind the form to the `comment` object. This uses [locals](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) to make it resuable so you would render the partial like so:

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't have a `new.html.erb` in my `views/comments` folder. I have a `template.html.erb` which renders two partials: `_form.html.erb` and `_reply.html.erb`. Which one should I render in the create method?

Comment: I would create a `new.html.erb` with just `<%= render partial: 'form' %>` its a bit of duplication but its better to have a designated view which follows the conventions.

Comment: the comments are nested so comments can reply comments. That's why I have `_reply.html.erb` and `_form.html.erb`. And I copied that from a blog. Why not use `template` or just rename it to `new`?

Comment: Because you want to stick with the rails conventions unless you have a really good reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your `form_for` submits a `POST` request which triggers the HTML format in `CommentsController#create`:

```
def create
    @comment = build_comment(comment_params)
    respond_to do |format|
        if @comment.save
            make_child_comment
            format.html
            format.json { redirect_to(:back, :notice => 'Comment was successfully added.')}
        else
            format.html
            format.json { redirect_to(:back, :flash => {:error => @comment.errors}) }
        end
    end
end
```

So, if `@comment.save` fails, and this is an HTML request, the `#create` method renders `create.html`. I think you want to render `Posts#show` instead.

Keep in mind that if validations fail on an object (Either by calling `save`/`create`, or `validate`/`valid?`), the `@comment` object will be populated with errors. In other words calling `@comment.errors` returns the relevant errors if validation fails. This is how your form is able to display the errors in @new_comment.errors.

For consistency, you'll need to rename `@new_comment` as `@comment` in the `posts#show` action, otherwise you'll get a `NoMethodError` on Nil::NilClass.

TL;DR: You're not rendering your form again with your failed `@comment` object if creation of that comment fails. Rename to @comment in posts, and `render controller: :posts, action: :show` if `@comment.save` fails from `CommentsController#create`

Comment: But `redirect_to :back` also goes back to `Posts#show`. What is the difference between rendering the `Posts#show` page again and `redirect_to :back`? If I need to render the `Posts#show` page how should I code? It asks me the post id which is not in the comment#create method.

Comment: You're doing `redirect_to :back` in your JSON response, not HTML.

Comment: So `redirect_to :back` requires to be in JSON format only? I tried `render post_path` but it asks for the post id. In my case I think it is the `commentable_id`.

Comment: No - `redirect_to :back` sends a location header with the contents of the `HTTP_REFERER` header from the request. Note that all browsers do not send this header so it is unwise to rely on it. And never use it in a JSON response.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. The default format should be HTML not json in my app.

Answer (score -1):

I have figured out the answer myself with the help of others here.

The reason is that I messed up with the JSON format and html format (typical noobie error)

To be able to display the errors using the code I need to change two places ( and change `@comment` to `@new_comment` as per @Anthony's advice).

1.

routes.rb:

```
resources :comments, defaults: { format: 'html' } # I set it as 'json' before
```

2.

CommentsController.rb:

```
def create
    @new_comment = build_comment(comment_params)
    respond_to do |format|
        if @new_comment.save
            make_child_comment
            format.html { redirect_to(:back, :notice => 'Comment was successfully added.') }
        else
            commentable = commentable_type.constantize.find(commentable_id)
            format.html { render template: 'posts/show', locals: {:@post => commentable} }
            format.json { render json: @new_comment.errors }
        end
    end
end
```